# Android Accessibility

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback, android-native-library

Android Accessibility - How can I customize Accessibility talk back while using **Native calendar** component?

Even Though I tried setting Accessibility manually by triggering calendar ID in both XML and Functionality. Need any other possibility to solve this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack! To help us help you, please include some code that we can reference, or check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask!